# How to change the size of my 'glow' effect on excel, when I use custom color?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

When I create a shape in Excel(2007) I apply some effects in it on **Format > Shape Styles > Shape Effects**, with one of them being "glow" with some predefined colors and sizes.

What I'm trying to do is, select a custom color in "More Glow Colors" and then change the size of the glow, but I can't do that! It stays limited to the first glow size, and I have not found any configuration on "format Shape" that I can format the Glow size.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the glow size first with a default color, then change the color. This will allow your custom color to have a larger glow size. There isn't a way to pick the color first and then the size unless it can be accessed via VBA.

Comment: Oh Thanks! Can't vote up, sorry ... I thought I did that, but I can't mouse over the colors again,because it screw everything...Thanks again! @Raystafarian